# calling a view in clicking on menu item using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am calling view on menu item click event using like this

```
  <div class="menuDiv">
      <ul class="menuUnorderedList">
        <li class="menuListItem"><a id ="menuItem1" href="loadSearchPage()" @*onclick="loadSearchPage()"*@>Search</a></li>
        <li class="menuListItem"><a  id="menuItem2" href="#" onclick="loadTransactionHistoryPage(this.Id)">Transaction History</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>

   <div class="rightPart">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
```

and the corresponding jquery function like this

```
 function loadSearchPage() {

            $.post("/SearchDisplay/" + action, function (data) {

                alert('1');
                $("#rightPart").html(data);
                loadPage('menuItem1');
            });

        }
```

my aim is if i click on the menuitem i need to call javascript function that will call the corresponding view  and this call need to be a full post back (entire page refresh).........

for that purpose i have done like mentioned above.

but I am not able to hit the javascript function (i.e), i am not able to display the alert inside that javascript function when i click on menuItem1 ...

is this approach is correct way or is there any better approach than this calling a view using javascript ..

would any one pls help on this ...

Many thanks....

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you are doing a full post back then why do you need to have a javascript? You can use `Url.Action` to generate the menu link which points to the respective `Action` method.

Comment: @Nilesh i need to call view when i click on the menu item ...where i need to use that url.action .. is it in click event ...

Comment: You need to do something like this `<a id ="menuItem1" href="Url.Action("YourAction","YourController",new { ParameterIfAny=ValueIfAny })" *@>Search</a>`

Comment: I am getting error when i click on the menuitem i have done like that u mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this,

```
function loadSearchPage() {
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("SearchDisplay", "Controller")';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
        <div id="menucontainer">

            <ul id="menu">              
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

Comment: Not sure whats not working. Are you getting an error? or are you not able to navigate at all? Cause this is the code that comes with standard code template of the _layout page.

Comment: yes if i click on menuitem it was giving server error 404 ....and this wont work in my situation ....

Comment: 404 means the resource was not found. Do you have the `Action` method in place? Are you calling the correct `Action` method?

Comment: yes everything is there, If i mention like yours i am not able to display the required item in menuitems ...

Comment: Is your application setup under a virtual directory? Did you check the URL generated in the HTML? WHat does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use "onclick" event of li tag instead of A tag

like :-

```
<div class="menuDiv">
  <ul class="menuUnorderedList">
    <li class="menuListItem" onclick="loadSearchPage()" ><a id ="menuItem1" href="loadSearchPage()"  >Search</a></li>
    <li class="menuListItem" onclick="loadTransactionHistoryPage(this.Id)><a  id="menuItem2" href="#" ">Transaction History</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: I suggest you to set href of A tag like :-  href="javascript:void(0);" .whatever you want to call call on li click event